# How to pass variable argument list to another printf like function?

Tags: c, parameters, printf

People say use `vprintf` instead of `printf`. But I can't because I need to use a function of my own.

- I have 2 custom functions
- both use va_list
- one function uses the other function

So is it possible to chain the `va_list` calls without having those v... functions ? And how ?

---

**Code:**

```
char* createString(const char* line, ...)
{
    char* result = (char*)malloc(100);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, line);
    vsprintf(result, line, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

void show(const char* line, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, line);
    char* a = createString(line, args);
    va_end(args);

    AfxMessageBox(a);
    free(a);
}

// usage:
show("test %i, %i", 12, 123);
```

When I try this I get wrong strings displayed. Instead of 12 and 123 I get some pointers or stuff.

**Sad solution:**

```
char* vCreateString(const char* line, va_list args)
{
    char* result = (char*)malloc(100);
    vsprintf(result, line, args);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. That's why the `v`-versions exist in the first place, to support passing on a `va_list`.

You need to make `createString()` accept a `va_list` argument.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and consider using [`vsnprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vsnprintf) to protect against buffer overflow.